# SQLite query planner not working as expected

Tags: sqlite

I am convinced the SQLite query planner is not working as reliably as one would
expect. Here is my proof. (I am running SQLite 3.39.2 compiled with
`ENABLE_STAT4`)

Given the following tables and indexes (I am showing only the relevant columns
and indexes below)

```sql
CREATE TABLE treatments ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    treatmentId TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    authorityName TEXT, 
    checkInYear INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
        (strftime('%Y', datetime(checkinTime/1000, 'unixepoch'))) VIRTUAL
);
CREATE INDEX ix_tr_treatmentId ON treatments (treatmentId);
CREATE INDEX ix_tr_authorityName ON treatments (authorityName COLLATE NOCASE);
CREATE INDEX ix_tr_checkInYear ON treatments (checkInYear);

CREATE TABLE materialsCitations ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    materialsCitationId TEXT NOT NULL,
    treatmentId TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (materialsCitationId, treatmentId)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_mc_treatmentId ON materialsCitations (treatmentId);
CREATE INDEX ix_mc_materialsCitationId ON materialsCitations (materialsCitationId);
```

The following query is really slow and is using an index for a column in the
`SELECT` clause but no index for the column in the `WHERE` clause

```sql
sqlite> ANALYZE;
Run Time: real 21.277 user 8.771114 sys 3.486287
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>     checkInYear, 
   ...>     Count (DISTINCT materialsCitations.materialsCitationId) AS num 
   ...> FROM 
   ...>     treatments 
   ...>     JOIN materialsCitations 
   ...>         ON materialsCitations.treatmentId = treatments.treatmentId 
   ...> WHERE 
   ...>     treatments.authorityName LIKE 'miller%' 
   ...> GROUP BY 1;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN treatments USING INDEX ix_tr_checkInYear
|--SEARCH materialsCitations USING INDEX ix_mc_treatmentId (treatmentId=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR count(DISTINCT)
checkInYear  num
-----------  ---
2015         1  
2016         10 
2017         2  
2018         6  
2019         28 
2020         351
2021         884
2022         34 
Run Time: real 17.524 user 0.204189 sys 2.224635
```

So I ask the expert and I create the suggested index and run `ANALYZE` again

```sql
sqlite> .expert
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>     checkInYear, 
   ...>     Count (DISTINCT materialsCitations.materialsCitationId) AS num 
   ...> FROM 
   ...>     treatments 
   ...>     JOIN materialsCitations 
   ...>         ON materialsCitations.treatmentId = treatments.treatmentId 
   ...> WHERE 
   ...>     treatments.authorityName LIKE 'miller%' 
   ...> GROUP BY 1;
CREATE INDEX treatments_idx_102f7cd4 ON treatments(treatmentId, authorityName COLLATE NOCASE);

SCAN materialsCitations USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_materialsCitations_1
SEARCH treatments USING INDEX treatments_idx_102f7cd4 (treatmentId=? AND authorityName>? AND authorityName<?)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR count(DISTINCT)

Run Time: real 0.001 user 0.000837 sys 0.000037
sqlite> CREATE INDEX treatments_idx_102f7cd4 ON treatments(treatmentId, authorityName COLLATE NOCASE);
Run Time: real 6.853 user 0.288260 sys 1.173741
sqlite> ANALYZE;
Run Time: real 21.838 user 8.883465 sys 3.560944
```

I run my query again and it doesn't use the index that SQLite itself
suggested!!! Of course, the query is slow.

```sql
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>     checkInYear, 
   ...>     Count (DISTINCT materialsCitations.materialsCitationId) AS num 
   ...> FROM 
   ...>     treatments 
   ...>     JOIN materialsCitations 
   ...>         ON materialsCitations.treatmentId = treatments.treatmentId 
   ...> WHERE 
   ...>     treatments.authorityName LIKE 'miller%' 
   ...> GROUP BY 1;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN treatments USING INDEX ix_tr_checkInYear
|--SEARCH materialsCitations USING INDEX ix_mc_treatmentId (treatmentId=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR count(DISTINCT)
checkInYear  num
-----------  ---
2015         1  
2016         10 
2017         2  
2018         6  
2019         28 
2020         351
2021         884
2022         34 
Run Time: real 12.417 user 0.193501 sys 1.682963
```

Running SQLite expert again results in no further suggestions

```sql
sqlite> .expert
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>     checkInYear, 
   ...>     Count (DISTINCT materialsCitations.materialsCitationId) AS num 
   ...> FROM 
   ...>     treatments 
   ...>     JOIN materialsCitations 
   ...>         ON materialsCitations.treatmentId = treatments.treatmentId 
   ...> WHERE 
   ...>     treatments.authorityName LIKE 'miller%' 
   ...> GROUP BY 1;
(no new indexes)

SCAN materialsCitations USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_materialsCitations_1
SEARCH treatments USING INDEX treatments_idx_102f7cd4 (treatmentId=? AND authorityName>? AND authorityName<?)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR count(DISTINCT)

Run Time: real 0.001 user 0.001244 sys 0.000029
```

So I force the query to use my own INDEX, one that already exists for
`authorityName`, the column in the `WHERE` clause. And now the query is
super-fast.

```sql
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>     checkInYear, 
   ...>     Count (DISTINCT materialsCitations.materialsCitationId) AS num 
   ...> FROM 
   ...>     treatments INDEXED BY ix_tr_authorityName
   ...>     JOIN materialsCitations 
   ...>         ON materialsCitations.treatmentId = treatments.treatmentId 
   ...> WHERE 
   ...>     treatments.authorityName LIKE 'miller%' 
   ...> GROUP BY 1;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN treatments USING INDEX ix_tr_authorityName
|--SEARCH materialsCitations USING INDEX ix_mc_treatmentId (treatmentId=?)
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR count(DISTINCT)
checkInYear  num
-----------  ---
2015         1  
2016         10 
2017         2  
2018         6  
2019         28 
2020         351
2021         884
2022         34 
Run Time: real 0.128 user 0.037315 sys 0.013139
sqlite>
```

This, to me, does not seem like expected behavior. What can I do?

Comment: One thing: `ix_tr_treatmentId` isn't needed, a UNIQUE column automatically gets an index already.

Comment: Try `CROSS JOIN` instead of plain `JOIN`? (Without the `INDEXED`)

Comment: Oh, you can also do `ANALYZE index_name` to save some time after adding an index instead of rebuilding the tables for everything.

Comment: tried `CROSS JOIN` without `INDEXED BY` but no improvement. SQLite query planner is still choosing the wrong index unless I change `GROUP BY 1` to `GROUP BY +checkInYear`. However, it is still not using the right index `ix_tr_authorityName` so the query is still slow